# Please assist to change ${average} output from decimal to whole number

Tags: javascript, html

My javascript calculation output showing decimal number, can someone assist me on how to change it to whole number. For an example, output for ${average} is **30.333333333333332** so I wants it to be **30**. Can someone assist on this?

**Code**

```
<div id="demo" align="center"></div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var selectedcount = '';
  var average = '';

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `
<table class="table table-striped table-dark" style="width:600px; float: right; margin-right: 330px;">
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center; color: #000000; text-align: left;">Predicted average for next semester:</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; color: #000000; text-align: left;">Approximately ${average} students</td>
  </tr>
</table>`

  }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#prg").change( function(){
      selectedcount = $('#prg option:selected').data('prgcount');
      if(selectedcount > 30){
        average = selectedcount / 3 + 5;
      } else{
        average = selectedcount / 3 - 5;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

P/S: I've removed some unrelated codes from this, I hope it helps.

**Output**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)?

probably this should work:

```
${Math.floor(average)}
```

it will Round the number downward to its nearest integer

Comment: This works well....thank you @Kostas Kapetanakis :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***toFixed*** function to get a rounded string by a number passed into that function e.g.:

```
selectedcount = 29;
// result without round 14,666...
average = (selectedcount / 3 + 5).toFixed(2); // to fixed 2 we get '14,66'
```

Here you get average string rounded by 2, for example selectedcount. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you @Damian Diaz - Kosta's code looks more easier btw. Thank you for your time... :)